# Windows Phone rendering issue in Monogame

Tags: mobile, xna, monogame, portrait

I'm trying to create portrait application but sprites are like this: [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA7Bp.png) I can render sprites **only** in Landspace correctly. How can I fix it? I'm thinking about programming air hockey. So I need to fix portrait problem.

Comment: Show us your codez

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got the orientation set to portrait but you forgot to change the resolution to match...

So this would be landscape:

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
```

and this would be portrait:

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 720;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1280;
```